# How can I call another component function from Angular Material Dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have Angular Application, I have a preview popup on my list data component the preview popup is a dialog component.

now when I click on button from my list I pass Id of list item, the dialogs display data from dialog component based on the Id passed to it. now I have set some actions on the dialog like Mark as complete
it calls a function in dialog component and updates the database, now I want once the database updated, I refresh my list component with latest data.

here is my code:

dialog component or (TaskspopupviewpcComponent):

```
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { Component, OnInit, Inject,SecurityContext} from '@angular/core';
import {TaskscalendarviewpcComponent} from '../taskscalendarviewpc/taskscalendarviewpc.component';
import { DialogService } from '../../../../shared/services/dialog.service';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ITasks } from '../../../models/tasks.model';

import { TasksService } from '../../../services/tasks.service';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';

//--------we add the router here for edit to redirect to edit form-----//
import { ActivatedRoute,Router } from '@angular/router';

      export class TasksData {
        constructor(public dynamicdata: string, public id: number, public action: string, public text: string, public type: string) {}
      }
      @Component({
        selector: 'app-taskspopupviewpc',
        templateUrl: './taskspopupviewpc.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./taskspopupviewpc.component.scss'],
        //template:`<app-taskscalendarviewpc #component1></app-taskscalendarviewpc>`
      })
      export class TaskspopupviewpcComponent implements OnInit {
        
        action;
        close;
        taskId: number;
        taskResult;
        type: string;

        taskname;
        category;
        startdate;
        enddate;
        textContent;
        textContent1;
        editorReadSantStyle = {
          height: '100px',
          alignment:'MJ Selected-Quill'
        };
        constructor(
          private _router:Router,
          private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
          public dialog: MatDialog,
          private dialogService: DialogService,
          private taskservice:TasksService,
          public callRef: MatDialogRef<TaskspopupviewpcComponent>,
          @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: TasksData,
          private sanitizer?: DomSanitizer,
          ) { 
            this.taskId = data.id;
            this.action = data.action;
            this.close = data.text;
            this.type = data.type;
          }

        ngOnInit(): void {
          this.getTaskById(this.taskId);
        }

        closeWindow(): void {
          this.callRef.close(false);
        }
        getTaskById(id) {
          this.taskservice.getTaskById(id,'/tasks/').subscribe(
            (thetask: ITasks) => this.dispalyTask(thetask),
            error => {
              const res = this.dialogService.ErrorDialog('Server Error', 'Sorry, the system is unavailable at the moment.', 'Close', 'Try Again');
              res.afterClosed().subscribe(dialogResult => {
                if (dialogResult) {
                  //this.callNext(200);
                }
              });
            }
          );
        }

        dispalyTask(task: ITasks) {
          this.taskResult = task[0];
          console.log(this.taskResult);
          this.taskId = task[0].TaskID;
          this.taskname = task[0].TaskName;
          this.category = task[0].CategoryName;
          this.startdate = formatDate(task[0].StartDate,'yyyy-MM-dd','en_US');
          this.enddate = formatDate(task[0].EndDate,'yyyy-MM-dd','en_US');

          //---fore here we hide the description----//
          //this.textContent = this.HTMLSant(task[0].Description);
        }

        HTMLSant(html:string){
          return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
        }

        markAsComplete(taskId){
          console.log(taskId);
          this.closeWindow();
          if(taskId>0){
            console.log('-----Update task-----');
            const result = {"TaskID":taskId,"Status":true};
            this.taskservice.updateStatus(result, taskId, '/tasks/updatestatus/').subscribe(
              res => {
                if (res) {
                  this.dialogService.MessageBox('Marked as Complete', 'X', 100, 'SuccessMessage');
                  //this.callNext(1000);
                  //this.refreshCalendar(100);
                } else {
                  this.dialogService.MessageBox('Error updating record', 'X', 5000, 'ErrorMessage');
                }
              },
              error => {
                const res = this.dialogService.ErrorDialog(
                  'Server Error',
                  'Sorry, the system is unavailable at the moment.',
                  'Close',
                  'Try Again'
                );
                res.afterClosed().subscribe(dialogResult => {
                  if (dialogResult) {
                    //this.callNext(200);
                  }
                });
              }
            );
          }
        }
        editTask(taskId:number){
          console.log(taskId);
          this.closeWindow();
          this._router.navigate(['./tasks/alltasks/addtask/',taskId]);
        }


      }
```

my list component or (TaskscalendarviewpcComponent):

```
import {Component,ChangeDetectionStrategy,ViewChild,TemplateRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {startOfDay,  endOfDay,  subDays,  addDays,  endOfMonth,  isSameDay,  isSameMonth,  addHours,} from 'date-fns';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {  CalendarEvent,  CalendarEventAction,  CalendarEventTimesChangedEvent,  CalendarView,} from 'angular-calendar';
import { ITasks } from '../../../models/tasks.model';

import { TasksService } from '../../../services/tasks.service';
import { DialogService } from '../../../../shared/services/dialog.service';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
//import { CalendarEventActionsComponent } from 'angular-calendar/modules/common/calendar-event-actions.component';
import { TasksData, TaskspopupviewpcComponent } from '../taskspopupviewpc/taskspopupviewpc.component';

      const colors: any = {
        red: {
          primary: '#ad2121',
          secondary: '#FAE3E3',
        },
        blue: {
          primary: '#1e90ff',
          secondary: '#D1E8FF',
        },
        yellow: {
          primary: '#e3bc08',
          secondary: '#FDF1BA',
        },
      }; 

      @Component({
        selector: 'app-taskscalendarviewpc',
        templateUrl: './taskscalendarviewpc.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./taskscalendarviewpc.component.scss'],
        providers: [DialogService]
      })
      export class TaskscalendarviewpcComponent implements OnInit {
        @ViewChild('modalContent', { static: true }) modalContent: TemplateRef<any>;

        view: CalendarView = CalendarView.Month;

        CalendarView = CalendarView;

        viewDate: Date = new Date();

        modalData: {
          action: string;
          event: CalendarEvent;
        };

        actions: CalendarEventAction[] = [
          {
            label: '<i class="fas fa-fw fa-pencil-alt"></i>',
            a11yLabel: 'Edit',
            onClick: ({ event }: { event: CalendarEvent }): void => {
              this.handleEvent('Edited', event);
            },
          },
          {
            label: '<i class="fas fa-fw fa-trash-alt"></i>',
            a11yLabel: 'Delete',
            onClick: ({ event }: { event: CalendarEvent }): void => {
              this.events = this.events.filter((iEvent) => iEvent !== event);
              this.handleEvent('Deleted', event);
            },
          },
        ];

        refresh: Subject<any> = new Subject();

        events: CalendarEvent[] = [];

        activeDayIsOpen: boolean = true;

        constructor(
          private modal: NgbModal,
          public dialog: MatDialog,
          private dialogService: DialogService,
          private taskservice:TasksService) {}

        ngOnInit(){
          console.log('---------Hi call db-----');
          this.getAllmyTasks();
        }

        getAllmyTasks(){

          this.taskservice.getAllMyPendingTasks('/tasks/getallmypendingtasks').subscribe(
            (myDbData: ITasks[]) => {
              console.log(myDbData);
              myDbData.forEach((item)=>{
                this.events.push({
                  id:item.TaskID, 
                  start:new Date(item.StartDate),
                  end:new Date(item.EndDate),
                  title:item.TaskName,
                  color: colors.yellow,
                  actions: this.actions
                })
              });
              this.viewDate = new Date();
            },
            error => {
              const res = this.dialogService.ErrorDialog('Server Error', 'Sorry, the system is unavailable at the moment.', 'Close', 'Try again');
              res.afterClosed().subscribe(dialogResult => {
                if (dialogResult) {
                  //this.callNext(200);
                }
              });
            }
          );
        }

        openPreview(action: string, event: CalendarEvent): void {
          let id:number = Number(event.id);
          const res = new TasksData('{data}', id, 'open', 'X', 'view');
          const req = this.dialog.open(TaskspopupviewpcComponent, { data: res, panelClass: 'mj-preview-modal' });
          req.afterClosed().subscribe(dataBox => {
            if (dataBox) {
              const data = dataBox;
            }
          });
        }

        //---------Calendar------------------------//
        dayClicked({ date, events }: { date: Date; events: CalendarEvent[] }): void {
          //--note this.viewDate is current date;
          console.log(date);
          if (isSameMonth(date, this.viewDate)) {
            if (
              (isSameDay(this.viewDate, date) && this.activeDayIsOpen === true) ||
              events.length === 0
            ) {
              this.activeDayIsOpen = false;
            } else {
              this.activeDayIsOpen = true;
            }
            this.viewDate = date;
          }
        }

        eventTimesChanged({
          event,
          newStart,
          newEnd,
        }: CalendarEventTimesChangedEvent): void {
          this.events = this.events.map((iEvent) => {
            if (iEvent === event) {
              return {
                ...event,
                start: newStart,
                end: newEnd,
              };
            }
            return iEvent;
          });
          this.handleEvent('Dropped or resized', event);
        }

        handleEvent(action: string, event: CalendarEvent): void {
          console.log(action);
          console.log('--------xxx------');
          console.log(event.id);
          let TaskId = event.id;
          this.modalData = { event, action };
          this.modal.open(this.modalContent, { size: 'lg' });
        }

        addEvent(): void {
          this.events = [
            ...this.events,
            {
              title: 'New event',
              start: startOfDay(new Date()),
              end: endOfDay(new Date()),
              color: colors.red,
              draggable: true,
              resizable: {
                beforeStart: true,
                afterEnd: true,
              },
            },
          ];
        }

        deleteEvent(eventToDelete: CalendarEvent) {
          this.events = this.events.filter((event) => event !== eventToDelete);
        }

        setView(view: CalendarView) {
          this.view = view;
        }

        closeOpenMonthViewDay() {
          this.activeDayIsOpen = false;
        }

        
      }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change dialog component as a Service and it worked, here is the working code:

```
          import {Component,ChangeDetectionStrategy,ViewChild,TemplateRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    import {startOfDay,  endOfDay,  subDays,  addDays,  endOfMonth,  isSameDay,  isSameMonth,  addHours,} from 'date-fns';
    import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
    import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
    import {  CalendarEvent,  CalendarEventAction,  CalendarEventTimesChangedEvent,  CalendarView,} from 'angular-calendar';
    import { ITasks } from '../../../models/tasks.model';

    import { TasksService } from '../../../services/tasks.service';
    import { DialogService } from '../../../../shared/services/dialog.service';
    import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
    //import { CalendarEventActionsComponent } from 'angular-calendar/modules/common/calendar-event-actions.component';
    import { TasksData, TaskspopupviewpcComponent } from '../taskspopupviewpc/taskspopupviewpc.component';

    import {TasksdialogService} from '../../../services/tasksdialog.service';
    const colors: any = {
      red: {
        primary: '#ad2121',
        secondary: '#FAE3E3',
      },
      blue: {
        primary: '#1e90ff',
        secondary: '#D1E8FF',
      },
      yellow: {
        primary: '#e3bc08',
        secondary: '#FDF1BA',
      },
    }; 

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-taskscalendarviewpc',
      templateUrl: './taskscalendarviewpc.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./taskscalendarviewpc.component.scss'],
      providers: [DialogService,TasksdialogService]
    })
    export class TaskscalendarviewpcComponent implements OnInit {
      @ViewChild('modalContent', { static: true }) modalContent: TemplateRef<any>;

      view: CalendarView = CalendarView.Month;

      CalendarView = CalendarView;

      viewDate: Date = new Date();

      modalData: {
        action: string;
        event: CalendarEvent;
      };

      actions: CalendarEventAction[] = [
        {
          label: '<i class="fas fa-fw fa-pencil-alt"></i>',
          a11yLabel: 'Edit',
          onClick: ({ event }: { event: CalendarEvent }): void => {
            this.handleEvent('Edited', event);
          },
        },
        {
          label: '<i class="fas fa-fw fa-trash-alt"></i>',
          a11yLabel: 'Delete',
          onClick: ({ event }: { event: CalendarEvent }): void => {
            this.events = this.events.filter((iEvent) => iEvent !== event);
            this.handleEvent('Deleted', event);
          },
        },
      ];

      refresh: Subject<any> = new Subject();

      events: CalendarEvent[] = [];

      activeDayIsOpen: boolean = true;

      constructor(
        private modal: NgbModal,
        public dialog: MatDialog,
        private dialogService: DialogService,
        private taskDialogService: TasksdialogService,
        private taskservice:TasksService) {}

      ngOnInit(){
        console.log('---------Hi call db-----');
        this.getAllmyTasks();
      }

      getAllmyTasks(){

        this.taskservice.getAllMyPendingTasks('/tasks/getallmypendingtasks').subscribe(
          (myDbData: ITasks[]) => {
            console.log(myDbData);
            myDbData.forEach((item)=>{
              this.events.push({
                id:item.TaskID, 
                start:new Date(item.StartDate),
                end:new Date(item.EndDate),
                title:item.TaskName,
                color: colors.yellow,
                actions: this.actions
              })
            });
            this.viewDate = new Date();
          },
          error => {
            const res = this.dialogService.ErrorDialog('Server Error', 'Sorry, the system is unavailable at the moment.', 'Close', 'Try again');
            res.afterClosed().subscribe(dialogResult => {
              if (dialogResult) {
                //this.callNext(200);
              }
            });
          }
        );
      }

      
      setStatusToComplete(action: string, event: CalendarEvent){
        let id:number = Number(event.id);
        const result = this.taskDialogService.openTasksDialog('',id,'myaction','Are you sure','mytype');
        result.afterClosed().subscribe(dialogResult => {
          if (dialogResult) {
            //this.deleteTaskById(TaskID);
            console.log('---------h--------dialog-----');
            this.markAsComplete(id);
          }
        });
      }

      markAsComplete(taskId){
        console.log(taskId);
        if(taskId>0){
          console.log('-----Update task-----');
          const result = {"TaskID":taskId,"Status":true};
          this.taskservice.updateStatus(result, taskId, '/tasks/updatestatus/').subscribe(
            res => {
              if (res) {
                this.dialogService.MessageBox('Marked as Complete', 'X', 100, 'SuccessMessage');
                //this.callNext(1000);
                //this.refreshCalendar(100);
                this.events = [];
                this.getAllmyTasks();
              } else {
                this.dialogService.MessageBox('Error updating record', 'X', 5000, 'ErrorMessage');
              }
            },
            error => {
              const res = this.dialogService.ErrorDialog(
                'Server Error',
                'Sorry, the system is unavailable at the moment.',
                'Close',
                'Try Again'
              );
              res.afterClosed().subscribe(dialogResult => {
                if (dialogResult) {
                  //this.callNext(200);
                }
              });
            }
          );
        }
      }


      openPreview(action: string, event: CalendarEvent): void {
        let id:number = Number(event.id);
        const res = new TasksData('{data}', id, 'open', 'X', 'view');
        const req = this.dialog.open(TaskspopupviewpcComponent, { data: res, panelClass: 'mj-preview-modal' });
        req.afterClosed().subscribe(dataBox => {
          if (dataBox) {
            const data = dataBox;
          }
        });
      }

      //---------Calendar------------------------//
      dayClicked({ date, events }: { date: Date; events: CalendarEvent[] }): void {
        //--note this.viewDate is current date;
        console.log(date);
        if (isSameMonth(date, this.viewDate)) {
          if (
            (isSameDay(this.viewDate, date) && this.activeDayIsOpen === true) ||
            events.length === 0
          ) {
            this.activeDayIsOpen = false;
          } else {
            this.activeDayIsOpen = true;
          }
          this.viewDate = date;
        }
      }

      eventTimesChanged({
        event,
        newStart,
        newEnd,
      }: CalendarEventTimesChangedEvent): void {
        this.events = this.events.map((iEvent) => {
          if (iEvent === event) {
            return {
              ...event,
              start: newStart,
              end: newEnd,
            };
          }
          return iEvent;
        });
        this.handleEvent('Dropped or resized', event);
      }

      handleEvent(action: string, event: CalendarEvent): void {
        console.log(action);
        console.log('--------xxx------');
        console.log(event.id);
        let TaskId = event.id;
        this.modalData = { event, action };
        this.modal.open(this.modalContent, { size: 'lg' });
      }

      addEvent(): void {
        this.events = [
          ...this.events,
          {
            title: 'New event',
            start: startOfDay(new Date()),
            end: endOfDay(new Date()),
            color: colors.red,
            draggable: true,
            resizable: {
              beforeStart: true,
              afterEnd: true,
            },
          },
        ];
      }

      deleteEvent(eventToDelete: CalendarEvent) {
        this.events = this.events.filter((event) => event !== eventToDelete);
      }

      setView(view: CalendarView) {
        this.view = view;
      }

      closeOpenMonthViewDay() {
        this.activeDayIsOpen = false;
      }

      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create **`service`** and then write function in that **`service`** and you can call it in any **`component`** ..

you can get perfect information about **How to create `service`** and **How to use it** from these links..

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular4/angular4_services.htm

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services